# IOS: как сжать данный UIView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Есть View и на нем два TextField и Button, при активной клавиатуре эти TextField и Button приподнимаются вверх на размер высоты клавиатуры, тоесть если TextField будет стоять высоко, то он уедет за экран. Помогите сделать так чтобы, это не происходило, нужно поменять размер view, но размер контролов лежащих на ней не менять, а поменять лишь координаты. Здесь готовый проект http://goo.gl/1OcLmn

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую использовать `UITableViewController` - он сделает эту работу за вас автоматически.
Чтобы не пересобирать `view` вы можете создать пустой `UITableViewController` и поместить ваше `view` в `tableHeaderView` или `tableFooterView`. После этого запускаем и видим как все само работает.

Comment: Интересно, а этот метод применим к сторибоард?